# How to merge two MySQL tables

Tags: mysql, sql, merge

**region** table

```
view    state         region
EB1     TamilNadu     Chennai-North
EB2     AndhraPradesh     Guntur
```

**country** table

```
view    code    country   state
EB1     +91     India     TamilNadu
EB2     +91     India     AndhraPradesh
EB3     +91     India     Delhi
EB4     +91     India     Delhi
```

I want to merge these tables based on view that not exists in `region` table.

**Result** table must be like below:

```
view    code    country   state
EB3     +91     India     Delhi
EB4     +91     India     Delhi
```

(where `EB1`,`EB2` exist in `region` table)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `LEFT JOIN` for that. You want values which do not exist on table `region`. So you need to use `WHERE r.view IS NULL`. You whole query should be:

```
   SELECT c.*
     FROM country c
LEFT JOIN region r
       ON c.view = r.view
    WHERE r.view IS NULL
```

#### [See this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3e9ca/2)

**UPDATE**

If you want to create a new table named `result` and want to add those values in that table, you can use the following query:

For creating a new table:

```
CREATE TABLE result
    (`view` varchar(3), `code` varchar(4)
     , `country` varchar(5), `state` varchar(13))
;
```

Inserting values on that table:

```
INSERT INTO result (`view`, `code`, `country`, `state`)
      SELECT c.view, c.code, c.country, c.state
        FROM country c
   LEFT JOIN region r
          ON c.view = r.view
       WHERE r.view IS NULL
```

#### [See this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/25e47/1)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a new table:

```
CREATE TABLE new_table (
  SELECT * FROM country
  WHERE view NOT IN (
    SELECT view FROM region
  )
)
```

or if you just want to create a view, use the same query, replace the `CREATE TABLE` by `CREATE VIEW AS`.